# Is it possible to verify ASHX syntax errors NOT at the run time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Basically there are simple errors in ASHX file (like missing comma or something like that). Everything is complied OK by Visual Studio, but once the file is accessed (hosted by IIS), an error pops up.

Is there a way to recognize such blunders in MSBuild or Visual Studio?

Comment: The problem is the ASHX isn't actually getting compiled - it's done on request by IIS. I think you can force this in VS by adding a Web Deployment Project (or something similar) to your solution but I'm not 100% sure what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ASP.NET compilation tool (`aspnet_compiler.exe`) to compile ASHX files. See MSDN, [*How to: Precompile ASP.NET Web Site Projects*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx).

Comment: Super. That's what I need for MSBuild. Thanks!